# How to deep Copy this linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

Hi I am having trouble making a method to deep copy this linked list I implemented.

```
    struct node_t {
      int priority,moves;
      int** data; // 2D matrix of integers
      struct node_t *prev_board;
    };
```

This is what I have so far. This methods takes in the source list and returns a deep copy list.

```
    struct node_t* copy_list(struct node_t* src, int len) {

    if (src != NULL) {
        struct node_t* list = malloc(sizeof(struct node_t));
        struct node_t* temps = malloc(sizeof(struct node_t));
        temps = src;
        while (src->prev_board != NULL) {
            list->prev_board = malloc(sizeof(struct node_t));
            list->data = (int **)malloc(len * sizeof(int *));
            int r = 0;
            for (r = 0; r < len; ++r) {
                list->data[r] = (int *)malloc(len * sizeof(int ));
            }
            copy_v(src->data, list->data,len); // Copies all the array values
            list->priority = src->priority;
            src = src->prev_board;
            list = list->prev_board;
        }
        list = temps;
        return list;
    }
    else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Is this correct approach and is this memory efficient aswell. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `struct node_t* list = malloc(sizeof(struct node_t*));` --> `struct node_t* list = malloc(sizeof(struct node_t));`

Comment: No, it is totally not. You are allocating a node and immediately throw it away: `temps = malloc(...); temps = src;` Same thing with `list = (something)` and afterwards `list = (simething else)`. You are not using correct sizes for malloc (see previous comment).

Comment: `int** data; // 2D matrix of integers` - NO! This is no and cannot point to a 2D array. And don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends.

Comment: Thanks @BLUEPIXY . Changed the sizes for malloc.

Comment: @Olaf What do you mean it can't point to a 2D array?

Comment: `int **` cannot point to something representing a 2D array. Many C programmers (including seniors)  and a lot of teachers who not really write C programs don't really understand pointers and arrays in C. They **think** (worse: tell others) this is  2D array. But they are wrong. This is a good way to judge if someone has understood this fundamental part of the C language. There are a lot of answers about that already.

Comment: ^^^ what @Olaf says.  A pointer to an array of pointers is NOT a 2D array.  A 2D array, ([x][y]),  of some type does not need any pointer/s.

Comment: @MartinJames: Well, if you dynamically allocate it, you have to use a pointer. But none inside the array itself (which I think is what you mean), nor that clumsy allocation for these double-indirection stuff.

Comment: @Olaf Ok thanks for informing me about that. I will adjust my code .